# Calculate $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^4 H(x)^2 e^{-x^2} dx$ where $H(x)$ is a Hermite polynomial

Tags: calculus, orthogonal-polynomials

I need to calculate the following integral

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^4 H(x)^2 e^{-x^2} dx.$$

where $H(x)$ is a Hermite polynomial.

I tried using the recurrence relation, but I don't get the answer.

Comment: Hello. What did you get?

Comment: What is $H(x)$?

Comment: $H(x)$ is a Hermite polynomial. this piece of info has been destroyed by a suggested edit. Please don't approve suggested edit when it destroy the original content.

Comment: @achillehui: Then I think he means $H_n(x)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I also believe the $H(x)$ here really means $H_n(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can have the closed form for your integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^4 H_n(x)^2 e^{-x^2} dx =  \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}{2}^{n}\left(2
> \,{n}^{2}+2\,n+1 \right)n!\,,\quad n=0,1,2,3,\dots\,. $$

**Added:** One can get a closed form formula for another integral involves the cubic Hermite

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x H_n(x)^3 e^{-x^2} dx= {\frac { 48\,(512)^n \Gamma  \left( n+\frac{3}{2} \right)^{3}}{\pi \, \left( n+1 \right) }}.\quad n=0,1,2,3,\dots\,.$$

Comment: And this follows from ... ?

Comment: @nbubis: I'll try to add more details later.

Comment: I think I found the method you used, although it'd be interesting if your argument differs.

Comment: @BennettGardiner: Good job. By the way, I added another identity if you are interested to prove.

Comment: @BennettGardiner: what method was used here?  It looks like the integral was plugged into Maple and the result copied into MathJax.

Comment: @RonGordon: Try Maple or Mathematica and see if you get an answer.

Comment: @Mhenni: I'm not interested in what Maple or Mathematica says beyond verifying what I get by hand.  I am interested in how one uses the properties of Hermite polynomials to determine the formula you posted, as nbubis also asked.  But I asked the OP because he seems to have divined your method, which if it is something other than copying output from Maple, it would be good to know.

Comment: @RonGordon: Usually, people have different interests in things.

Comment: @RonGordon, did you see my post? I was able to derive the answer by hand, but if Mathematica can do integrals of this type that is also interesting. In fact, using the method I give we should now be able to conquer all integrals of the form
$$
F(n,m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, [H_n(x)]^2x^{2m}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x,
$$
although we would require some other generating function involving cubes of the Hermite polynomials to evaluate the new integral that Mhenni has presented.

Comment: Note that, from Wikipedia, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_m(x) H_n(x)\, \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{ \pi} 2^n n! \delta_{nm},$$
which gives us confirmation on the value of $F(n,0)$.

Comment: I would appreciate if you give me steps (esp the second added cubic one) ... (+1)

Comment: Steps are in my post below, plus discussion. Anyone have any ideas on the cubic one? Even better would be a result for
$$G(n,m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^m [H_n(x)]^3 e^{-x^2} dx,$$ I am guessing that even $m$ values will be zero?

Comment: Seems if $n$ and $m$ have different parity then the answer for the cubic one is zero!

Comment: Where did you get these from, @MhenniBenghorbal? Can you share the method/mathematica code you used?

Answer (score 5):

This paper, ["On the Squares of Hermite Polynomials"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02189685#page-1), tells us that
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{[H_n(x)]^2z^n}{2^nn!} = \frac{\exp{(2x^2z/(1+z))}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}.
$$
Multiplying by $x^4\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$ and integrating gives that
$$
\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{[H_n(x)]^2x^4\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}z^n}{2^nn!} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(2x^2z/(1+z)-x^2)}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}x^4 \, \mathrm{d}x. 
$$
The integral on the right hand side is a classical integral from statistical physics, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(2x^2z/(1+z)-x^2)}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}x^4 \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-x^2(1-z)/(1+z))}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}x^4 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{3\sqrt{\pi}(1+z)^2}{4(1-z)^3}.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{(1+z)^2}{(1-z)^3} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ (2n^2+2n+1) \ z^n, \qquad \mbox{for} \ |z|<1,
$$
which gives us the result that @Mhenni Benghorbal mentioned (under the caveat that we can swap the summation and integration on the left hand side).

Now, let's try to evaluate the more general case of
$$
F(n,m) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \, [H_n(x)]^2x^{2m}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
We repeat the above process, where on the right hand side we have to evaluate integrals of the form
$$
(1-z^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \,x^{2m}\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{(1+z)^{m}}{(1-z)^{m+1}}\Gamma\left(\frac{2m+1}{2}\right).
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{(1+z)^{m}}{(1-z)^{m+1}} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^{n+1}, 
$$
where $c_0=1$, $c_1=2m$ and $(2+n)c_{n+2} -2mc_{n+1}=nc_n$ (I won't attempt to solve the recurrence relation - even solving for our $m=2$ case in Wolfram Alpha gave the result in terms of something called the Lerch Transcendental!). In any case, 
$$
F(n,m) = 2^nn!c_n(m)\Gamma\left(\frac{2m+1}{2}\right).
$$
For the special case $m=0$,
$$
F(n,0) = 2^nn!c_n(0)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =  2^nn!\sqrt{\pi},
$$
which confirms a well known result (from Wikipedia), that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_m(x) H_n(x)\, \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x =  2^n n! \sqrt{ \pi}\delta_{nm}
$$

Comment: Edit - Note that the initial generating function reference if from Erdelyi, A., Magnus, W., Oberhettinger, F. and Tricomi, F. G.,Higher transcendental functions, Vol. 2. McGraw Hill, New York-Toronto-London, p. 194.